# Code gives Null Pointer Exception Error

Tags: android-ndk

I am receiving values from other activities and with these values try to fetch the data from the database but NullPointerException will occur

```
    final Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String topic=bundle.getString("topic");
 String subtopic=bundle.getString("subtopic");
```

My  Database Query is

```
public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().query("Q_A", new String[] { "_id",
                "Question","QLevel", "TopicId", "SubTopicId" }, "TopicId=? AND SubTopicId=?",
                new String[] { topic + "", subtopic + "" }, null, null,
                null));
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `getReadableDatabase()` returns null. Where did you get it?

Comment: ourCursor = helper.getAll(); here i call my getAll() method

Comment: i think the problem is in the Bundle code when i replace that code from the code given below then it runs ok
      final String topic="1";
      final String subtopic="3";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mu guess is correct you are sending intent datatype as Integer from previous activity  and receiving as String in Current Activity.

Ensure that you send String type and getting String type.

Change your code to :

```
final Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String topic=bundle.getInt("topic");
String subtopic=bundle.getInt("subtopic");
```